# How to convert vector wrapped as string to numpy array in pandas dataframe?

Tags: arrays, string, pandas, numpy, type-conversion

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of vectors that I would like to perform matrix arithmetic on.  However, upon closer inspection the vectors are all wrapped as strings with new line characters seemingly embedded in them:

[image]

How do I convert each vector in this column into numpy arrays?  I've tried

```
df['Word Vector'].as_matrix
```

and

```
np.array(df['Word Vector'])
```

as well as

```
df['Word Vector'] = df['Word Vector'].astype(np.array)
```

but none produced the desired result.  Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: profide an example of your data that we can experiment with.

Comment: @MedAli what would be the best way to do so?  I wasn't sure of the process was that generated this format, how can I upload a sample of the dataframe to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hope the following works as what you expected

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = str(np.arange(1,100))
df = pd.DataFrame([x,x,x,x])
df.columns = ['words']
print 'sample'
print df.head()
result = df['words'].apply(lambda x: 
                           np.fromstring(
                               x.replace('\n','')
                                .replace('[','')
                                .replace(']','')
                                .replace('  ',' '), sep=' '))
print 'result'
print result
```

output as following

```
    sample
                                               words
0  [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
1  [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
2  [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
3  [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
result
0    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, ...
1    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, ...
2    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, ...
3    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, ...
```

It is not elegant to call replace function so many times. However I did not find better approach. Anyway it should help you to convert string to vectors.

A side note, as data is presented in picture, You'd better check whether your data separation is done by space or tab.  If it is tab, change sep=' ' to sep='\t'

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for string lists in a Pandas column:

```
df['Numpy Word Vector'] = df['Word Vector'].apply(eval).apply(np.array)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is shorter:

```py
df[col_name] = df[col_name].apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x)), 0)
```

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['[0., 1., 2., 3.]', '[1., 2., 3., 4.]'], columns=['Word Vector'])
df['Word Vector'][0] # '[0., 1., 2., 3.]'

df['Word Vector'] = df['Word Vector'].apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x)), 0)
df['Word Vector'][0] # array([0., 1., 2., 3.])
```